# Client Certificate on iOS: Best Practices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, client-certificates

I am developing an application that will use a personal client certificate to verify the user's identity. The user will be issued the certificate from their company/organization, and will then have to install it on the phone somehow.

So my question is this: is it better for them to install it in the phone's built in storage, and the app would pull this cert from the OS, OR have the user add the cert to the application's doc folder via iTunes and load it from there?

The advantage of the cert being in the doc folder is that it's easy to locate an load into the app, but I'm not sure if that is considered "best practice."

Is there anyone out there who has actually done client certificates who can offer their input on the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through my research I have discovered that Apple does not support client certificates/PKI at this time. However if someone finds a work around, or if Apple adds this feature, please post your information here.